# Laravel get data from the foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have two table one is called `Submission` one called `AssignSubmission`

`Submission` belongTo `AssignSubmission`

```
public function assignsubmission()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AssignSubmission');
}
```

`AssignSubmission`hasMany`Submission`

```
public function submissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Submission');
}
```

They are linked with foreign keys 
In `AssignSubmission` has `id`, `user_id` and `submission_id` the foreign key is submission_id.
In Submission table, it has `id`, `user_id` and `file`, `url` etc

in `AssignSubmission` `submission_id` -> links to -> `Submission` `id`.
I have assigned different submission to 2 users.
[image]

How can I get data from the foreign key?
I want to display the url or file in the view

[image]

Comment: if "AssignSubmission submission_id -> links to -> Submission id" then your relationships are backwards!  The table with the foreign id `belongsTo` the other table.  So since `AssignSubmissions` table has `submission_id`, the `AssignSubmissions` belongsTo `Submissions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `Submission` object `$submission` already,

`$submission->assignSubmission->url` will give you the url.

It converts to camalCase for property name.

Comment: if I have 2 url in the submission, I only want the 2nd data, how can I display this?

Comment: I am assuming you mean 2 urls in the `assignmentSubmission`, if so, you could just treat `$submission->assignSubmission` as a normal `assignSubmission`, which means however you could access the second url on a normal `assignSubmission`, like `$assignSubmission->urls[1]`, you could do the same to `$submission->assignSubmission` like `$submission->assignSubmission->urls[1]`. It depends on your `AssignSubmission` model solely now, not related to relationships with `$submission`.

Comment: I have question to, why some times getting data using this way is showing an error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: @JuMa That's because the object before "->" is not an object, usually it's null. for example, `$submission->assignSubmission->url` in this case failing can be a result of `$submission` or `$submission->assignSubmission` being null.

Answer (score 2):

I think your relationships might be backwards?

Submission:

```
public function assignSubmissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AssignSubmission::class);
}
```

AssignSubmission:

```
public function submission()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Submission::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laravel relation. Then you can do this: (assuming that your submission table model is named `Submission`

```
App\Submission::with('assignsubmission')->get();
```

Comment: In my case, Submission' s id is AssignSubmissiom foreign key. `$assignsubmissions = Submission::with('assignsubmission')->get();`I didn't get it.

Comment: `AssignSubmission` has only one `Submission`?

Answer (score 0):

You have written the wrong relationship, It should be like this
 Submission:

```
public function assignSubmissions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Submission');

    }
```

AssignSubmission:

```
public function submission()
     {
             return $this->belongsTo('App\AssignSubmission');
     }
```

To get the results,i am considering Submission and AssignSubmissions is your models, so you can fetch like,

```
$submission = App\Submission::find(1)->assignSubmissions; 
$assignSubmissions = App\AssignSubmissions::find(1)->submission;
```

Check this link for more reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: I re-written the relationship now what is next, How I get the data from foreign key and get the  url displayed

Comment: @DonaldDonald What query your are trying to do now?

Comment: I am considering Submission and AssignSubmissions is your models, so you can fetch like,

$submission = App\Submission::find(1)->assignSubmissions;

$assignSubmissions = App\AssignSubmissions::find(1)->submission;

Comment: So in `AssignSubmission` I have `user_id` and `submission_id` I want to display the url of file in the view

Comment: Which file URL?

Comment: `url` or `file` is save in `Submission` table you can see in the picture I upload

Comment: Use the foreach loop if you have a single result for  $assignSubmissions Otherwise you have to make foreach loop for $assignSubmissions as well and then

    foreach ($assignSubmissions->submission as $assignSubmission) 
            //and access like $assignSubmission->url this.
    endforeach

Comment: Check this link to get more detailed idea, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many
Hope your issue is resolved, If yes, kindly accept the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182557/discussion-between-amol-rokade-and-donald-donald).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

*Submissions Model*

```
public function assignsubmission()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\AssignSubmission');
}
```

*AssignSubmission* Model

```
public function submissions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Submission','submission_id');
}
```